# NSMutableArray Crashing App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash, nsmutablearray

In one class, I define an `NSMutableArray` with getters and setters:

```
@interface ArrayClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *array;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;

@end
```

Then within the implementation file, I `alloc` `init` the mutable array:

```
#import "ImageUploader.h"

@implementation ArrayClass
@synthesize array;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        NSLog(@"ArrayClass inited");
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then I initialize an instance of this class from another class:

```
ArrayClass *arrayClass = [[ArrayClass alloc] init];
                [arrayClass.array addObject:image];
                NSUInteger count = [arrayClass.array count];
                NSLog(@"%@", count);
```

But when I try to add an object to the mutable array, the app crashes and Xcode 4.3 shows:
[image]

Removing the `addObject` call makes the app run fine. What am I doing wrong that would cause the app to crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
NSUInteger count = [arrayClass.array count];
NSLog(@"%@", count);
```

You want:

```
NSLog(@"%u", count);
```

`%@` is used to specify that the argument is an object. However, an NSUInteger is a primitive value, not an object. You use `%u` for unsigned ints.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
NSLog(@"%i", count);
```

NSUInteger return an INT not an object address

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"%@", count);
```

is wrong, use:

```
NSLog(@"%i", count);
```

`%@` in the format statement expects and must be an object, `NSUInteger` is in int, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `%@` format specifier, which is for Cocoa objects only, for an `NSUInteger`, which is a typedef on an ordinary `unsigned int`. Use %d, %i or %u instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's crashing when trying to print description, which makes sense because you're using `%@` where an integer is expected in your `NSLog()`.

Separately, using a mutable property is almost always a bad idea. If it's really a property, you probably want to use an immutable array, and set the whole array when you want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that the logging of count is wrong, but I think the other answers miss a move obvious point: the crash happens on the addObject.  This implies that image is nil.  NSLog that before the add.

Comment: Actually, the NSLog was the source of the crash. Should have narrowed down my question more.